# Meteor batch update

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm using meteor. I'm wondering if theres a shorthand way to do batch updates before the DOM is updated.

for instance I want to update some records,*more than one* (All at once):

```
Collection.update(id1,{..})
Collection.update(id2,{..})
Collection.update(id3,{..})
```

The problem is there are 3 items being updated separately. So when the DOM in my case was being redrawn 3 times instead of once (with all 3 updated records).

Is there a way to hold off the ui updating until all of them are updated?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Execute them on the server instead, that way they *might* be synchronously done such that they are less likely to cause multiple DOM updates on the client.

See the [first two and last interesting code bits](https://github.com/meteor/madewith/blob/master/README.md), which explain how to protect your clients from messing with the database as well as how to define methods on the server and call them from the client.

Comment: Im still not sure whether its asynchronous but it is already more optimal to do it this way

Answer (score 26):

Mongo's update can modify more than one document at a time.  Just give it a selector that matches more than one document, and set the `multi` option.  In your case, that's just a list of IDs, but you can use any selector.

```
Collection.update({_id: {$in: [id1, id2, id3]}}, {...}, {multi:true});
```

This will run a single DB update and a single redraw.

Comment: Suppose there is a property test in each of the documents matched by the above mongo selector and i wish to update test properrty with different values for each document, is that possible in some way ?

The way i understand your answer above is that i can $set any single field with a fixed static value and all the documents matched by _id will be affected. But i don't have a fixed value.